# Monitor function completion and talk to client

Tags: python, twisted

I think I'm doing some asynchronous like programming and I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I have a `function X` running on a new thread and a twisted tcp server on the main thread. I want to pass a message to the client when `function X` finishes its job. The code looks something like this:

```
val = None

def x():
    global val
    #do something to val and send message to client that val is ready

class Server(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(b'REDPY*')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("Packet: ",data)


class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print("new client")
        return Server()

threading.Thread(target=x).start()

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1235").listen(EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I've looked into deferred in twisted and event handling, im not really sure what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing messages from one task to another and then to clients over a network is tricky. And when threads are involved,  it can feel like you're working in the Twilight Zone :) Bad jokes aside, here's a simple snippet based on your example:

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
import threading

from twisted.internet import endpoints, protocol, reactor, task


def x(shutdown_event, queue):
    while not shutdown_event.is_set():
        # do something to val and send message to client that val is ready
        queue.put(b'data')

    print('thread done')


class Server(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        # append client to list in factory
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        self.transport.write(b'REDPY*')

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        # remove client from list after disconnection
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("Packet: ",data)


class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):

    protocol = Server

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []


def pop_from_queue(queue, factory):
    try:
        data = queue.get(timeout=0.5)

        # process data after this point

        # loop through the clients and send them stuff
        for client in factory.clients:
            # NOTE: ensure the data sent is in bytes
            client.transport.write(data)
    except Empty:
        pass


def main():
    factory = EchoFactory()
    queue = Queue()
    event = threading.Event()

    # when the reactor stops, set Event so that threads know to stop
    reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', event.set)
    # periodically check and pop from the queue
    periodic_task = task.LoopingCall(pop_from_queue, queue, factory)
    periodic_task.start(1)

    threading.Thread(target=x, args=(event, queue)).start()
    endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1235").listen(factory)


main()
reactor.run()
```

The basic things you have to get out of this is:

- there's a shared `Queue` object between the threads
- the `Factory` object holds a list of `clients`
- removed your `buildFactory` overload and just set the `protocol` attribute in `EchoFactory`. You don't need to do anything fancy in this case so it's best to leave it be. Also, by default, Twisted will set a `self.factory` attribute in the protocol.
- when a client connects it appends to `factory.clients`, the client is removed after `connectionLost`
- there is a `LoopingCall` task that will `pop_from_queue` periodically

I also added an extra shut down `Event` that's set when the reactor shuts down and it will be possible to gracefully shutdown the threads. If anything is unclear please comment and I'll explain more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically doing multithreaded programming here.  It doesn't matter so much that you're using Twisted in the main thread.  You still need some threadsafe communications primitives.  The only way Twisted might make a difference is if it offers some facilities to accomplish your goals *without* using threading.  Neither your question nor your example make it clear *what* your goals are so I can't provide any guidance in that direction (so, next time, consider being more specific and detailed in your question to potentially get a better answer).

You can use `Queue` as a thread-safe(-ish) inter-thread communication mechanism.

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue

def x(reactor, queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        # ... processing

threading.Thread(target=x).start()

# ...
reactor.run()
```

You can also skip the long-running thread and just use Twisted's thread-pool for short-lived operations.

```
a_deferred = deferToThread(some_task, ...)
a_deferred.addCallback(deal_with_result_of_task)
```

Comment: I’m trying to build a neural network server, where function X basically loads the weights to the network as soon as the script is executed and starts the server to handle requests. In order to handle requests the server needs to send messages to clients that the neural network is loaded with weights and is ready.